# Tkinter/ImageTk 'AttributeError' when displaying a png image

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use a **PNG** image in a Tkinter Button widget with the help of ImageTk module from PIL library.

```
image = Image.open(os.path.join('icons','bulb.png')) # using PIL for png images
        self.correctGuessImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

While working fine under windows 7x64 it fails to work on Linux Mint x64. I am getting this error running the same file.

```
  File "/home/user/Documents/temp.py", line 222, in drawButtons
    self.correctGuessImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 171, in paste
    im.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 192, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getdecoder'
```

I installed everything I could find with 'python','png' and 'tk' from the reps but no effect. Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed zlib?

Comment: You could try Pillow instead of PIL, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this strange issue. If you're using Linux Mint, you'll be installing pillow from the reps, don't! First make sure you have `tk8.5-dev` and `tcl8.5-dev` packages and install *pillow* via PIP.

```
$ sudo pip install pillow
```

PIP shall build pillow on your machine with tk and tcl dev packages installed, which shall resolve the problem mentioned above. Make sure you don't have `python-imaging-compat` the actual PIL library because Pillow and PIL are incompatible. I find this quite frustrating as users of HP printers won't be happy not to be able to use hplip (dependency of python-imaging-compat)

I found the advice on [this page](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/322).